# Centralizar verticalmente icone (img) seguido de texto em um linha

Tags: html, css

Quero colocar em uma linha um icone, de 25x25px (que vai ser também um link) e um texto e ambos tem que ficar centralizados verticalmente, para isso tentei esse html:

```
<p>
    <a href="mailto:utilizador@dominio.com.br" target="_blank">
        <img src="icons/25mail.png" />
    </a> utilizador@dominio.com.br
</p>
```

e esse css:

```
p {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    margin: 8px 0 5px 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

Mas o icone fica um pouco mais pra cima em relação ao texto, como faço para centralizar ambos em relação a altura da linha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você precisa ajustar é o `vertical-align` da imagem.

Teste usar isto no seu CSS:

```
img { vertical-align: text-bottom; }
```

Exemplo sem especificar `vertical-align`: http://jsfiddle.net/KZxab/1/
Exemplo com `vertical-align: text-bottom;`: http://jsfiddle.net/KZxab/

Pode mesmo dar um valor em pixeis, positivos ou negativos caso queira respetivamente subir ou descer a imagem.

Exemplo com `vertical-align: -20px;`: http://jsfiddle.net/KZxab/2/

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado!